# React Native Map unable to dynamically render multiple different image array markers

Tags: react-native, google-maps-markers, react-native-maps

I am trying to dynamically display 2-3 different sets of marker images on React Native maps in Android, however I am at most able to render only one category of marker image. I tried using 2 sets of marker arrays, 1 for each image, as well as a conditional rendering of marker image. Has anyone else had experience doing something like this?

Comment: please show us your code so far

Comment: @carlosdafield I just figured it out... it wasn't a problem with the code, but for some reason that particular image did not show when rendered on screen.